# Symfony 4 : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: symfony4

Hello someone can help me please ? I don't know why I have an error when I try to run my project.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in E:\wamp64\www\BlogCv\public\index.php on line 15

Full code :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2HWK.png

Comment: You need PHP 7.0 at least

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify your environnement ?

Following this [link](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony#v4.4.21) you have got a minimal php version and i think your need an upgrade php version.

Comment: Thanks but I have another problem :( "Attempted to load class "DoctrineCacheBundle" from namespace "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are running your application on a old PHP version (like 5.6 or something), the null coallescing operator (??) is only available for PHP 7.0 or more.

you can check the PHP version in you php.ini file or with the command line

```
php bin/console about

 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Symfony
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Version              3.2.5
  End of maintenance   07/2017
  End of life          01/2018
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Kernel
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Type                 AppKernel
  Name                 app
  Environment          dev
  Debug                true
  Charset              UTF-8
  Root directory       ./app
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (587 KiB)
  Log directory        ./var/logs (1.5 MiB)
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  PHP
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Version              7.1.3 <====== HERE
  Architecture         64 bits
  Intl locale          en_US_POSIX
  Timezone             America/New_York (2017-03-31T16:55:46-05:00)
  OPcache              true
  APCu                 true
  Xdebug               false
```

Comment: I'm running php 7.4.16 and still dosent work :(